# Returning objects reference in java?

Tags: java

So i'm preparing for an exam and trying to figure this one out, whether it breaks encapsulation or not. No idea if with question even makes sense, but I'm working on a game that has a bunch of server classes and a client class Game.
In my Player class I have this field

```
private Room currentRoom;
```

and a accessor method:

```
public void getCurrentRoom {
    return currentRoom;
}
```

Room class has:

```
private String Name;
private ArrayList<Item> items;
private HashMap<String, Room> exists;
```

I've used the get method seven different places in the Game class, but I don't know if it breaks the principle of encapsulation by returning it directly - if it does, what would a better approach be?

Thank you.

Comment: are you sure your `getCurrentRoom` compiles?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Note the word **complete**. This means that anyone should be able to compile your code just as it is.

Answer (score 0):

First off, this code won't compile, since it needs to return an instance of type `Room`

```
public void getCurrentRoom {
    return currentRoom;
}
```

Does it break the principle of encapsulation?

**No.**

**Principle of Encapsulation:**

> Encapsulation helps to create code that is loosely coupled. Because
>   the details are hidden, it reduces the ability of other objects to
>   directly modify an object's state and behavior.

- Since your getter callers wouldn't know how the current room was set,
  it has hidden its implementation behind the scenes.
- Your function to set the current room needs to be `private` in order
  to hide the implementation

Source:

https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-the-oop-principle-of-encapsulation--gamedev-2187